# How to install packages from archiso.img - Arch linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I have a fresh Arch linux installation with all the base packages installed. I saw some nice packages in live boot and I want them in my installation as well. How can I do that with using the live image.?

Answer (score 1):

You can view [the list of packages on the iso](https://git.archlinux.org/archiso.git/tree/configs/releng/packages.x86_64): as you can see, it is not a long list.

Rather than copying the likely already outdated `*pkg.tar.xz` across to your new system and then installing them with `pacman -U $package`, you are much better advised to just install them from an up-to-date mirror with `pacman -Syu $package`.

If you want to include them in the initial package install with the `pacstrap` command, you can just append the package name to the standard command:

```
pacstrap /mnt base $package1 $package2 $package3
```

Not only will this mean that you do not (inadvertently) perform [a partial update](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_maintenance#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported), it will also ensure that all of the required dependencies for the package are correctly installed.